# hidepid=2 stopped working after an update. Kernel don't suppport “per-mount point”?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd, fstab, hardening

I am running arch linux hardened (5.11.13-hardened1-1-hardened) and have been setting hidepid=2 thru the fstab:

```
proc            /proc       proc        nosuid,nodev,noexec,hidepid=2,gid=proc  0 0
```

and in the and override file for systemd-logind.service as hidepid.conf:

```
[Service]
SupplementaryGroups=proc
```

All accordning to the [arch wiki security](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/security#hidepid) and everything has been working fine up until a while ago after an update, and I think it is because of systemd-248 update, but I am obviously not sure.

When reading up on systemd changes a came across this section about "ProtectProc=" which is being set in the systemd-logind.service now by default, so I have been setting this option to 'invisible' (which does not take effect) and that should obsolete the fstab setting of hidepid=2 but in the description of "ProtectProc=" here [freedesktop systemd protectproc=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#ProtectProc=)

```
If the kernel doesn't support per-mount point hidepid= mount options this setting remains
without effect, and the unit's processes will be able to access and see other process as if 
the option was not used. This option is only available for system services and is not supported
for services running in per-user instances of the service manager.
```

So what is the meaning of this? Anyone else out there who is experiencing this? Is this something I can fix thru kernel parameters in the hardened kernel?

Hope I did not miss this is the previous asked question in the forum.

Best regards

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html says `default` is the default for `ProtectProc=`, and "If [set to] "default" no restrictions on /proc/ access or visibility are made.". Where did you get that `invisible` would be the default and did you try manually adding it?

Comment: Very sorry forr this mistake, I meant that the 'ProtectProc=' is the new default way to set hidepid according to the text, and that I have set it to invisible. I will change this in the text right away.